# Raspberry Pi GPIO input help

Tags: gpio, python

[I have this rocker switch.](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5PCS-12V-20A-Car-Auto-Cover-White-LED-SPST-Toggle-Switch-Control-On-Off-WST-/300955478355?pt=UK_CarsParts_Vehicles_CarParts_SM&hash=item4612582953)

[image]

I have it connected on the GND pin to GPIO pin 11 (BCM 17) and a 1 kohm resistor to GND on the Raspberry Pi, the 3.3 V pin from the Raspberry Pi to positive:

```
Switch '+' -> 3.3 V
Switch '-' -> GPIO ALSO to resistor and then GND of the Raspberry Pi.
```

I have this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if(GPIO.input(11) == True):
            print("switch ON")
    else:
            print("switch OFF")
```

But it only ever says that it's off. Why is this?

Comment: I'm confused as to your connections.  Is it Pi ground to 1K resistor to switch contact #1.  Switch contact #2 to gpio17?  I'm not sure what the 3.3V pin is doing.

Comment: Pi GPIO 17 is directly on the gnd pin of the switch. On the switch's gnd is also a resistor and then to the Pi's gnd. 3v3 goes to the switch's positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help!

In the end, I tried this which works.
[image]

```
 Black is gnd of Pi
 Green is GPIO input pin
 Red is 3v3 pin of Pi
```

Is this safe?

Comment: That Black wire is doing, absolutely nothing :) I bet if you remove it, it will still work. Unless by luck, the Black Wire PIN is common with the Green wire PIN, in which case its like the circuit I posted. Just using 3.3V to GPIO in will work fine, but it not really recommended.

Comment: I took out the gnd and it doesn't work after that...

Answer (score 2):

In the schematic (borrowed) you can see GND is connected to the GPIO. This provides a LOW state which means the switch is OPEN. When you close the switch the GPIO will read high. The resistor is 10 kohm, but 1 kohm is also OK. That value only matters if you are trying to save battery power.

**Make sure to use 3.3 volt and not 5 volt.**

[image]

Comment: If the switch is closed and the gpio is (accidentally) set to be a low output would that cause damage, i.e. pop one or more gpios?  Why not put the switch between resistor and gpio?  With an internal pull-up to 3.3V.  The gpio will then normally read 1, but read 0 when the switch is closed.

Comment: Software is human error. To prevent that you can place a diode on the 3.3v. But reversing the circuit is also acceptable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I have. So 3v3 goes to the + on the switch and the switch's - goes to gpio and (via resistor) to gnd?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your switch doesn't appear to work.  The usual reason is it's not connected to the gpio you are using in software.

I think setting up BOARD numbering will use the P1 pin numbers.  So when you refer to 11 you are referring to P1-11 (which is attached to Broadcom gpio 17).

http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals

Personally I'd wire the switch as follows

Pi ground - resistor - switch - gpio

and set the internal pull-up on the gpio to 3.3V.

The resistor acts as a safety device in case the gpio is accidentally set as a high output.  Without a resistor there would be a short to ground and the gpio might be damaged.

Any resistor in the range 300-10,000 ohm should be fine.

With the above set-up the gpio will read 1 if the switch is open and 0 if closed.